# Search comparing two date fields

Tags: search, dates

I would like to be able to create a smart group of contacts who:
1) are participants for an event in the future
2) have passport expiration dates (a custom Individual Contact date field) that are before the End Date of said event

I'm not finding any way to compare the two date fields. I've looked at CiviRules, but that doesn't seem to get me what I need.

Any suggestions?

(Joomla 3.7.5, Civi 4.7.21)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's unlikely you'll be able to perform this search within any of CiviCRM's existing searches.

Fortunately, it's possible to [create custom searches](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-search). The process requires some coding, but gives you a tremendous amount of power and flexibility.

Comment: If you need help creating custom searches, you can contact a [CiviCRM expert](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) who can do the coding for you, or you can join the [developer chat room](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev) and ask questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that there's no way to do date comparisons like this out of the box.  You would have to write a custom search to handle this scenario.