# Compare fields in CiviRule?

Tags: civirules

Is there a way to compare Fields in CiviRule? I need a rule that adds a relationship based on the identity of a field. Something like "compare if new contact has an external ID that already exists and then link them together as partner organizations".

Is this possible?

(I found this [old post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20323/search-comparing-two-date-fields) back to '17)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do some comparison in CiviRules using the Field Value Comparison condition. Assuming that your external ID is a custom field (in CiviCRM an external identifier has to be unique....) you might be able to work your way through. It might mean you have to develop a specific condition though.

And please note that the "link them together as a partner organization" is an action, not a condition :-) And it will definitely be bespoke development, but possible.

Comment: thanks Erik. I managed in a different way but this was an opportunity to discover the Field Value Comparison and use it in the future.